# An error occurred while updating (Plugin Name): Update package not available

Tags: wordpress

As you can probably tell by the title, I am having trouble with updating a plugin via my WordPress CMS dashboard. Here's there error code:

```
An error occurred while updating MotoPress Content Editor: Update package not available.
```

It told me this, so I proceeded to delete the plugin via FTP and reinstall. It reinstalled the old version for some reason. How can I get the latest?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely license key is not activated for your plugin. You can get you license key and control website activation at your personal account https://www.getmotopress.com/my-account/
Also you can download latest version of plugin at your account and install it via **Dashboard>Plugins>Add New>Upload** (do not forget to remove currently installed plugin before installing latest version)